# Cant compile x64 LD_PRELOAD using x86 g++

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

Whats wrong with my command? I want to compile x64 ld_preload on x86 g++, command:

> g++ -fPIC  -m64 -shared -Wl,-soname,test.so -ldl -o test.so
>   test.cpp

error

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_tree.h:62,
>                    from /usr/include/c++/4.4/set:60,
>                    from test.cpp:17: /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algobase.h:60: fatal error:
>   bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
>   make: *** [test.so] Error 1

17 line test.cpp

```
#include <set>
```

Package g++-multilib installed.

**upd**

File search:

```
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/4.4
 /usr/include/c++/4.4/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The file `bits/c++config.h` in GNU C++ library is architecture dependent.

The 32 bit version is in

```
 /usr/include/c++/4.4/i486-linux-gnu/bits/c++config.h
```

or similar depending on the distribution.

On 32 bit platform the 64bit version is in

```
 /usr/include/c++/4.4/i486-linux-gnu/64/bits/c++config.h
```

**Edit**

To check which directories are searched type:

```
$ g++ -m64 -c -v test.cpp
```

It should report something like

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i486-linux-gnu
...
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/4.4
 /usr/include/c++/4.4/i486-linux-gnu/64
 /usr/include/c++/4.4/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
```

You need to check if

```
 /usr/include/c++/4.4/i486-linux-gnu/64
```

is on the list.

Also check that the file

```
/usr/include/c++/4.4/i486-linux-gnu/64/bits/c++config.h
```

exists.

Comment: There is no directory x86_64-linux-gnu, only i486-linux-gnu and i686-linux-gnu. How can i add it with -I?

Comment: what directory should be searched and what file should be there? I confused a bid...

Comment: @Robert Do you get any further when you run `g++ -fPIC -m64 -shared -Wl,-soname,test.so -ldl -I/usr/include/c++/i?86-linux-gnu/64 -o test.so test.cpp`?